# Vue: Functional component doesn't receive props

Tags: vue.js, components

The component `smart-list` does it's job and is rendering the correct component.
It just doesn't pass on the props. I'd expect them to be in a `context.data` but it is `undefined`.

`SmartList.vue`

```
import EmptyList from "./EmptyList";
import FullList from "./FullList";

export default {
  functional: true,
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array
    }
  },
  render(h, { props, data, children }) {
    if (props.items.length > 0) {
      return h(FullList, data, children);
    } else {
      return h(EmptyList, data, children);
    }
  }
};
```

I have prepared a [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/7w2qzyrz30)

What do I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. In the `smart-list` component I've changed one line:

```
import EmptyList from "./EmptyList";
import FullList from "./FullList";

export default {
  functional: true,
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array
    }
  },
  render(h, { props, data, children }) {
    if (props.items.length > 0) {
-    return h(FullList, data, children);
+    return h(FullList, { attrs: props }, children);
    } else {
      return h(EmptyList, data, children);
    }
  }
};
```

Now it works.
Can someone point me why passing the full `data` object doesn't work?